# R remove rows where an entry is not a date

Tags: r, date

I have a data frame where one column is (meant to be) a date in the form `00:00:00.0 yyyy-mm-dd`. Most of the entries are, but some are not. Is there a way to delete the rows that contain non-dates? Something like (if the column is "DATE")

```
data <- data[is.Date(DATE)==TRUE,]
```

For example.

```
Fruit  Date
apple  00:00:00.0 2005-02-01
pear   00:00:00.0 2006-02-01
orange 00:00:00.0 -8-2-402145
rhino  00:00:00.0 2003-04-21
```

I want

```
Fruit  Date
apple  00:00:00.0 2005-02-01
pear   00:00:00.0 2006-02-01
rhino  00:00:00.0 2003-04-21
```

Comment: Could you convert them to a date-time format using `strptime` and then anything that "isn't" a time will end up being `NA`, and hence easily removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following joran's reasoning:

```
# get the test data
test <- data.frame(
    Fruit=c("apple","pear","orange","rhino"),
    Date=c("00:00:00.0 2005-02-01",
           "00:00:00.0 2006-02-01",
           "00:00:00.0 -8-2-402145",
           "00:00:00.0 2003-04-21")
)

# remove the rows by checking if not (!) an NA due to not meeting the date format
test[!is.na(strptime(test$Date,format="00:00:00.0 %Y-%m-%d")),]
```

Result:

```
  Fruit                  Date
1 apple 00:00:00.0 2005-02-01
2  pear 00:00:00.0 2006-02-01
4 rhino 00:00:00.0 2003-04-21
```